# How can I access PubMed's database using BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, pubmed, google-patent-search

When accessing `google_patents_research.publications` table from BigQuery I can filter results by the `top_terms` column. This column uses Google's machine learning algo to search the text inside a patent and extract the words it finds most meaningful.
I was wondering if there is a similar search using BigQuery that can be done on PubMed's database.
According to NCBI docs there is a dataset called `nih-sra-datastore` which should be accessible from BigQuery, but it doesn't show up when searching for it in BigQuery's console search box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to `nih-sra-datastore` as explained on this page [The National Center for Biotechnology Information](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/docs/sra-bigquery/) it looks that its making reference to the project-id not the dataset as such.

So in order to have access to it you have to follow these steps (on BigQuery explorer):

- Click on `+ADD DATA`
- Hover over `Pin a Project` and select `Enter a Project Name`
- Add `nih-sra-datastore`

You will pin this public project to your BigQuery explorer.

Comment: Has the bigQuery UI been updated because I'm not seeing 'Pin a project' anywhere in the current dialogue when I click `+ ADD DATA`? I've been trying to figure out how to add `nih-sra-datastore` and haven't been able to figure it out using the docs (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/docs/sra-bigquery/) seems like they are out of date or missing a step